# Creating Local Notification when terminating Application

Tags: notifications, application-lifecycle

In my app, i should show a local notification whenever i am terminating app by double clicking home button. I have tried this one using **applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)** method. some times it showing notification and some some times not showing when i am terminating app. Now i used "**viewWillDisappear**" . it showing notification first time i am terminating app. second time if i terminate same screen it not showing notification. Is there any way to create notification whenever i am terminating same screen.

Comment: Log the didReceiveLocalNotification method, and schedule the notification after 10 or 20 sec from the current time.

Comment: Good to hear. welcome...